# HTC One / Beats Earbud Conflict

Tags: audio, headphones, htc-one

The Beats earbuds that came with my HTC One initially worked great: the inline control worked, sounded decent. Recently, the phone fails to recognize them however. When I plug in alternative earbuds the phone plays music through the alts. When I plug the Beats earbuds into  alternative audio sources, the earbuds themselves work fine.

There appears to be a conflict between the two together:

- I have tried using the headphone controls apps to see if throwing an app in there dedicated to managing the earbud controls would be a workaround and this did not work.
- When I plug the Beats earbuds in, music plays through the phone speaker but the earbuds make the noise they would due to being plugged into a sound source
- I have tried this with the Beats Audio setting on and off, and it is not a separate volume settings issue as the phone plays music through itself instead of the earbuds
- Essentially, the issue isn't even with the inline controls, it is with audio not coming out at all; having audio come out of them would suffice a win for me

What are my options and which are the best:

- Get a new set of the same headphones; confirm if the issue is with this specific pair, and perhaps a short inline or other wear issue?
- Is there some kind of Software solution?
- Is the phone the problem even if other headphones work with it?

Comment: When you say, "the earbuds make the noise they would due to being plugged into a sound source," do you mean they make the kind of clicking noise the same way they usually would when you plug them in? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @DanHulme that's correct; they make the usual sound that's kind of a staticky click (for lack of a better way to explain) that any line makes when being plugged in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

I have been recently using my beats tour with my HTC One. It was working fine and then it stopped working. First I thought either my phone had a problem or the earphones. I thought of claiming my warranty but, before that I did following tests:

1. Plugged different earphones in my HTC One from Apple, Samsung and HTC. All worked fine.
2. Plugged my Beats earphone with iPhone, iPod and my computer. It was working fine too.

## Analysis

Then I compared the connector of Beats earphone with others. I noticed a potential design flaw with both Beats connector and HTC One:

1. Beats earphone connector radius is slightly smaller than normal earphone connectors.
2. HTC One internal connector was pushed in more when plugging and unplugging earphone.
   *(I don't exactly know words to explain this but, this usually happens with electronics when using cheap materials)*.

## Solution

As I am sure both HTC and Beats won't be accepting these facts. I recommend you to buy a short extender. I connected my extender to my HTC One and Beats earphone and it worked like expected.

[image]

I am not sure if we lose quality when using a cheaper extender.

Comment: Can you give us a link to that extender? Looks like what I need now.